# Problema ao somar valores da coluna e exibir no highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Tenho a tabela:

```
 numitens  |  data    |  email
 1         | 01/01/15 | exemplo@exemplo.com
 1         | 01/01/15 | exemplo@exemplo.com
 2         | 01/01/15 | exemplo@exemplo.com
 1         | 02/01/15 | exemplo@exemplo.com
```

O formato que gostaria de exibir os dados no gráfico seria o total da quantidade de itens à partir do dia.

Código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src='highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>      
<script src='exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
<meta charset="utf-8">


</head> 
<body> 


<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error connecting to server');
       mysql_select_db("sandbox", $con);           
       $SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM highchart";



       $result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
       $data1 = array();
       $data2 = array();
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
           $data1[] = $row['data'];
           $data2[] = ($row['numitens']);
       } 
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type: 'line' //spline, line, column
          }, 
          credits: {
      enabled: false
  },
  exporting: { 
    enabled: false 
  },
        title:  { text: 'Estatísticas' }, 
        xAxis:  { categories: ['<?php echo join("','", $data1) ?>'],}, 
        yAxis:  { min:0, }, 
        legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 50,
                    y: 35,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                }, 
        plotOptions: { column: { pointPadding: 0.3, borderWidth: 0 }}, 
        series: [{ name: 'Data', data: [<?php echo join(',',$data2) ?>],
                       // pointStart: 0
                        //pointInterval
                    },]
    });
});
</script> 

<div id="container" style="min-width: 1024px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 800px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: Gráfico gerado]

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem sua solicitação, o mais apropriado seria contar o número de itens por dia usando o próprio SQL:

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT sum(numitens) as numitens,data FROM highchart group by data";
```

Feito isso você já poderá plotar um gráfico com datas no eixo X e quantidades no eixo Y.

ENTRETANTO, se você deseja que o Highcharts interprete seu eixo X como datas de verdade ao invés de dados igualmente espaçados (se você tivesse 3 datas 01/01/2015,02/01/2015,10/01/2015 elas ficariam igualmente espaçadas no eixo X....bem talvez você queira isso mesmo), você precisa passar as informações de data assim (detalhe, os meses começam do 0):

```
Date.UTC(2015,0,1)
```

E você precisa colocar esse atributo no xAxis:

```
type: 'datetime',
```

Esse exemplo talvez ajude: http://jsfiddle.net/hdd8zjkn/